# URL rewrite( I think? )

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a URL: www.example.com/my_cool_pancakes. When a User goes to this URL, I would like the URL to instead be www.example.com/pancakes. How do I do this? Is this URL rewriting? I have studied URL rewriting, but I am still not sure about how it works, or even if it is the method I should use to do this. If it is, could you show me how? Thank you :)

PS: www.example.com/my_cool_pancakes is an archive page template for a custom post type if that makes any difference.

Comment: have you tried Changing the slug to `pancakes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could using the register_post_type parameters fit your needs? There's an option "slug" that will do so if has_archive is set to true...

Comment: I think that worked!